# Site coordinates?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS to teach a course about groundwater modeling, and I’d like to be able to set up conceptual problems in a “site coordinate” manner that isn’t projected from any georeferenced projection, but simply a cartesian system in feet or meters. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Open the Project Menu > Properties > CRS > "No projection (or unknown/non-Earth projection)"**

If you hover over that option, a description pops up:

> Use this option to treat all coordinates as Cartesian coordinates in an unknown reference system.

[image]

Comment: I can’t believe it. I’ve looked at that dialog a hundred times and never saw the silly checkbox. Sigh. Thank you!